# Unable to see stored procedure columns in Data Source Config wizard

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rdlc, rdl

I am working on configuring an RDLC for a project in Visual Studio. To the related stored procedure I added 3 columns. Now, while configuring the Dataset to include the new columns, I am not able to see any of the output columns for the selected stored procedure.

My test procedure:

```
CREATE proc test
    @Center_ID TINYINT = NULL
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    CREATE TABLE #test_tbl
    (
         col1 VARCHAR(20), 
         col2 VARCHAR(20)
    )

    INSERT INTO #test_tbl
    VALUES ('COL1', 'COL2')

    SELECT
        col1, col2
    FROM 
        #test_tbl
```

Now, in Visual Studio, I am not seeing the col1 and col2 check boxes in the Data source config wizard:

[image]

How do I make the columns show up in the wizard?!

Thanks!

Comment: The objects you are seeing are the stored procedures available.  Add the test proc and the columns should be included with the proc.

Comment: You mean in the question? I have added the proc already in the question.Pls clarify

Comment: No, I mean the columns won't show up in that window from your screenshot.  It's only showing procs.  Add the proc as a database object and the columns should appear in your report dataset.

Comment: Steve can you mention the steps here to add my proc as DB object?

Comment: Isn't it just as simple as checking the box next to `test` and clicking next?

Comment: Right If I do so nothing gets added. Because it is not recognizing  the columns of 'Test' sproc and so add nothing